# Setting relative location of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm trying to keep a JLabel that says "Welcome" in the middle of the panel, however, when I resize the frame, the label seems to change position, when I wish it to stay put in the center.
Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame 
{
    // Initialization of Attributes
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();

    // Labels
    JLabel menuTitle = new JLabel("Welcome!");

    public Frame()
    {
        /*
        All Frame Customizations
        */
        mainFrame.setSize(1200, 800);
        mainFrame.add(mainMenu);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        /*
        All Menu Customizations
        */
        mainMenu.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainMenu.setLayout(null);

        // Menu Title
        mainMenu.add(menuTitle);
        menuTitle.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 36));
        menuTitle.setBounds( (mainFrame.getWidth()/2) - 100, (mainFrame.getHeight()/2) -200,200, 80);

        // Border
        mainMenu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(8, 8, 8, 8, Color.BLACK));
    }

}
```

Here's the frame before resizing:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FcDW.png)

Here it is after resizing:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikix.png)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the reason why you should not use null-layout. Use appropriate [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead. See the [Layout Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) swing tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, makes much more sense now